# AWS IAM Users, Groups & Policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have only 1 bucket called "partners" & then I am creating folders under it for each of our partners. Then I create an IAM user for each partner and the goal is to give them access to their individual folder. So, if I have two partners/users called Alice & Bob, I want to give each of them access to their individual folders called Alice & Bob under the "partners" bucket. The goal is not to give S3 Console access, just programmatically they should be able to read/write/modify their content in those folders.

So, I was thinking of simply creating "inline policy" for each IAM user to restrict them to their folder. Is this the correct way or are there other alternatives? Here is my current "inline policy" for IAM user Alice.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListBucketIfSpecificPrefixIsIncludedInRequest",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::partners"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "alice/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToReadWriteObjectDataInProperFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::partners/alice/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ExplicitlyDenyAnyRequestsForAllOtherFolders",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::partners"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "alice/*",
                        ""
                    ]
                },
                "Null": {
                    "s3:prefix": false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're trying to achieve? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528195/creating-iam-policy-for-amazon-s3?rq=1

Comment: @xeon, I think so. It seems from the response that I have to create a policy for each user - Alice & Bob & any more in the future. I was looking for more universal group policy or a combination of group & inline policy to tackle this.

Comment: I think I am also trying to figure out if I have more users (partners) like Alice & Bob each with restrictive access to their respective home folders, do I need individual groups for each of them with separate policy (because of home folder name). If yes, thats fine. I am just trying to understand & arrive at a good scalable solution. Thanks in advance.